# How to identify & exclude 3rd-party ActivityType (e.g. 'Send to Kindle', 'Chrome') in a UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55137403/2272431) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39710905/2272431), it's possible to exclude other `ActivityType` options using  `UIActivityViewController`'s `excludedActivityTypes`, beyond just those which are pre-defined.

However, how does one find out the identifiers for any given `ActivityType` (ideally programmatically at build-/run-time, if possible), so they can then be excluded?

For example, I'm looking to disable **Send to Kindle** and **Chrome**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out the `ActivityType` of a third party activity, select that activity after displaying your `UIActivityViewController`.

When the completion handler is called, completion closure/block you provided to the activity controller has a parameter with a type of `ActivityType` telling you which one was chosen.

For example:

```
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
    print("activity: \(activity), success: \(success), items: \(items), error: \(error)")
}
```

Now you know the `ActivityType` for that activity. Update your code to add that value to the list you pass to `excludedActivityTypes`.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while to work out exactly how to do this, so I've edited your answer with some example code. 
I'm also going to edit the question so it's more focused on getting the identifier for any activity. Hopefully you'll get more votes that way.

Comment: Unfortunately, even though I got the exact identifiers from this method, they still aren't being excluded. Any idea why this wouldn't be working?
```let kindleActivity = UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.amazon.Lassen.SendToKindleExtension"); let chromeActivity = UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.google.chrome.ios.ShareExtension"); activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [kindleActivity, chromeActivity]```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that UIActivityViewController does not honor every activity type you try to exclude. I've run into this in the past and I'm sure I've similar similar questions posted. It's almost as if you can only exclude activities that have a constant listed for ActivityType.

Comment: That's a real shame. It doesn't appear to be all without a constant, because I did manage to exclude `UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension")` and `UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension")`, which don't seem to have their own, but they are also iOS-native activities, so this might be why they worked.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, as determined by @[rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy)'s excellent answer, these are the specific identifiers for **Send to Kindle** and **Chrome**, if anyone's interested:

```
let kindleActivity = UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.amazon.Lassen.SendToKindleExtension")
let chromeActivity = UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.google.chrome.ios.ShareExtension")
```

There are many other examples already defined in [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005258/ios-disabling-whatsapp-in-uiactivityviewcontroller/55137403#55137403).

Unfortunately, even when these are added to the array for `excludedActivityTypes`, they still seem to show up in the `UIActivityViewController`. Any input on why, and how this can be fixed, is very welcome!